# Date like yyyy/yy to yyyy (ex :2016/17 to 2016)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has a column `years`, and the data is like `2016/17`; `2017/18`, etc.

Until now I have this code:

```
SELECT champion 
FROM championship
WHERE season = (select to_char(sysdate - 730, 'yyyy') from dual)
```

I want to select, for example, the champion 2 years ago. How can i do that?

I was thinking to split 2016/17 (this is a varchar) to get only the 2016, but how?

This is a "simple" question, so, I would like to do without functions or anything like that.

Comment: Note: subtracting `730` is *not* the same as "2 years ago".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use substr :

```
SELECT champion
FROM championship
WHERE substr(season,1,4) = (to_char(sysdate - interval '2' YEAR,'YYYY') from dual)
```

`to_char(sysdate - interval '2' YEAR,'YYYY')` is better than `to_char(sysdate - 730, 'yyyy')`, example :

```
+------------+------------+---------+
+ Date       | -730 day   + -2 year +
+------------+------------+---------+
| 2018-12-31 | 2016-12-31 + 2016    +
| 2019-12-31 | 2017-12-31 + 2017    + 
| 2020-12-31 | 2019-01-01 + 2018    + ==> different year
| 2021-12-31 | 2020-01-01 + 2019    + ==> different year
| 2022-12-31 | 2020-12-31 + 2020    +
| 2023-12-31 | 2021-12-31 + 2021    +
| 2024-12-31 | 2023-01-01 + 2022    + ==> different year
| 2025-12-31 | 2024-01-01 + 2023    + ==> different year
+------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: `(select to_char(sysdate - 730, 'yyyy') from dual)` can be simplified to `to_char(sysdate - 730, 'yyyy')`

Comment: If you use an expressio on both sides of the predicate the DBMS won't be able to use any simple indexes, OTOH it can use an index if you use `season LIKE (TO_CHAR(sysdate - 730, 'yyyy') || '%')`. However there is unlikely to be enoiugh cardinality in the data for this to help performance in the absence of other predicates.

Comment: We can also use as Function-Based Indexes to increase performance

Comment: `ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -2*12)` is even better as it will also work on February 29th in leap year.

Comment: I think `sysdate - interval '2' YEAR` works on February 29th in leap year too, no ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `sysdate - 730`, use `INTERVAL` years. Further, You won't require `SUBSTR` to extract first 4 characters if your seasons are always of the form `<year/year+1>`

```
WHERE season = 
    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' YEAR,'YYYY') ||'/'|| 
    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' YEAR,'YY')
```

Comment: I agree with you `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2')` is better